# Combine two arrays after using filter method

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter

I am stuck showing the cart page where the products are listed which were added to Cart by Users.
I have two arrays: 
One with the product details.

```
productDetails: [
            {
              productID: 1,
              productTitle: 'Product Title 1',
              productPrice: 2000
            },
            {
              productID: 2,
              productTitle: 'Product Title 2',
              productPrice: 5000
            },
            {
              productID: 3,
              productTitle: 'Product Title 3',
              productPrice: 1000
            },
            {
              productID: 4,
              productTitle: 'Product Title 4',
              productPrice: 10000
            }
          ],
```

Another with Cart Product details which has productID and quantity selected by users only.

```
cartProducts: [
            {
              productID: 1,
              quantity: 5,
            },
            {
              productID: 3,
              quantity: 2,
            }
          ]
```

I have filtered all the products that the user have selected.

```
cartItemDetails() {
      return this.productDetails.filter(
        el => this.cartProducts.some(f => f.id === el.productID),
      );
    },
```

This function gives the product details of productID 1 and 3.
What i want is a new array that adds the quantity attribute of cartProducts array to productDetails array.

```
newArray: [
            {
              productID: 1,
              productTitle: 'Product Title 1',
              productPrice: 2000,
              quantity:5
            },
            {
              productID: 3,
              productTitle: 'Product Title 3',
              productPrice: 1000,
              quantity:5
            }
          ]
```

I hope i have made my questions clear. I am also trying to solve this issue with map javascript method but its not working.

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) after `filter()` and add `quantity` property to each item.

```js
const productDetails = [{ productID: 1, productTitle: 'Product Title 1', productPrice: 2000 }, { productID: 2, productTitle: 'Product Title 2', productPrice: 5000 }, { productID: 3, productTitle: 'Product Title 3', productPrice: 1000 }, { productID: 4, productTitle: 'Product Title 4', productPrice: 10000 }];
const cartProducts = [{ productID: 1, quantity: 5 }, { productID: 3, quantity: 2 }]; 

function cartItemDetails() {
  return productDetails
    .filter(el => cartProducts.some(f => f.productID === el.productID))
    .map(item => ({
      ...item,
      "quantity": cartProducts.find(f => f.productID === item.productID).quantity
    }));
}

console.log(cartItemDetails());
```

Or you can use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const productDetails = [{ productID: 1, productTitle: 'Product Title 1', productPrice: 2000 }, { productID: 2, productTitle: 'Product Title 2', productPrice: 5000 }, { productID: 3, productTitle: 'Product Title 3', productPrice: 1000 }, { productID: 4, productTitle: 'Product Title 4', productPrice: 10000 }];
const cartProducts = [{ productID: 1, quantity: 5 }, { productID: 3, quantity: 2 }]; 

function cartItemDetails() {
  return productDetails.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    let item = cartProducts.find(f => f.productID === curr.productID);

    if (item) {
      acc.push({ ...curr,
        "quantity": item.quantity
      });
    }

    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(cartItemDetails());
```

You can also use `map()` on `cartProducts`.

```js
const productDetails = [{ productID: 1, productTitle: 'Product Title 1', productPrice: 2000 }, { productID: 2, productTitle: 'Product Title 2', productPrice: 5000 }, { productID: 3, productTitle: 'Product Title 3', productPrice: 1000 }, { productID: 4, productTitle: 'Product Title 4', productPrice: 10000 }];
const cartProducts = [{ productID: 1, quantity: 5 }, { productID: 3, quantity: 2 }]; 

function cartItemDetails() {
  return cartProducts.map(item => ({
    ...productDetails.find(f => f.productID === item.productID),
    ...item
  }));
}

console.log(cartItemDetails());
```

Comment: Very much appreciated. Thank you for different variety of answers. I am accepting this answer among others due to its variety of methods.
Thank You

Answer (score 4):

Use map and object spread to combine the two arrays:

```
var newArray = cartProducts.map(cart => ({
  ...cart,
  ...productDetails.find(prod => prod.productID === cart.productID)
}));
```

Comment: Thank YOu for your answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Convert the `productDetails` to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (`productDetailsMap`), using the `productID` as the key.

Iterate the `cartProducts` with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) get the current product from `productDetailsMap` by it's `productID`, and merge by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) into a new object.

```js
const productDetails = [{"productID":1,"productTitle":"Product Title 1","productPrice":2000},{"productID":2,"productTitle":"Product Title 2","productPrice":5000},{"productID":3,"productTitle":"Product Title 3","productPrice":1000},{"productID":4,"productTitle":"Product Title 4","productPrice":10000}]
const cartProducts = [{"productID":1,"quantity":5},{"productID":3,"quantity":2}]

const productDetailsMap = new Map(productDetails.map(o => [o.productID, o]))

const result = cartProducts.map(o => ({
  ...productDetailsMap.get(o.productID),
  ...o
}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank You for the clean code. your answer is so clean and simple. Thank You

Answer (score 3):

You can try something similar to this:

```
cartItemDetails() {
    return this.cartProducts.map(cp => {
         let prod = this.productDetails.find(pd => pd.productID === cp.productID)
         return {...cp, ...prod}
    })
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank YOu for your answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.assign()` method to copy property-value pairs from productDetails into cartProducts whenever the productID matches:

```js
let productDetails = [
            {
              productID: 1,
              productTitle: 'Product Title 1',
              productPrice: 2000
            },
            {
              productID: 2,
              productTitle: 'Product Title 2',
              productPrice: 5000
            },
            {
              productID: 3,
              productTitle: 'Product Title 3',
              productPrice: 1000
            },
            {
              productID: 4,
              productTitle: 'Product Title 4',
              productPrice: 10000
            }
          ];

let cartProducts = [
            {
              productID: 1,
              quantity: 5,
            },
            {
              productID: 3,
              quantity: 2,
            }
          ];
cartProducts.map(cart => Object.assign(cart, productDetails.find(product => product.productID === cart.productID))  )
console.log(cartProducts)
```

Comment: Thank YOu for your answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
cartProducts.map(cartProduct => {
  return {
    ...productDetails.find(product => product.productID === cartProduct.productID),
    "quantity": cartProduct.quantity
  }
});
```

You could do some null checks if required.

Comment: Thank YOu for your answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is what is messing with your code here :

```
cartItemDetails() {
      return this.productDetails.filter(
        el => this.cartProducts.some(f => f.id === el.productID),
      );
    },
```

`f` which is a `cartProducts` item has no property `id`.

I think what you meant is `f.productID` instead.

Now here is a way to add the `quantity` property using the `map` function :

```
this.productDetails = cartItemDetails().map((element) => {
  for (let e of this.cartProducts) {
    if (e.productID === element.productID) return {...element, quantity: e.quantity}
  }
})
```

Comment: Array cartProducts had id element in my local code. While posting question I changed it to be more clear. 
And thank you for your answer.